# .NET Web Api controller is returning Http 200 status code on exception

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am making Ajax call using JQuery client.

```
var ajaxCalls = [];
 ajaxCalls.push(executeOne());
 ajaxCalls.push(executeTwo());

function executeOne() {

            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: URL,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(Params),
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }
        ;

        function executeTwo() {

            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: URL,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(ParamsTwo),
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }
        ;




$.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).then(function () {
     //DO something

 }).fail(function () {
                //Do something 
        }).always(function () {

        });
```

On the .net side, I have a simple contorller, where I am throwing an exception:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Results(ParamsModel data)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error");

    }
```

**Problem**: The status code is returned as 200 instead of 500. Becaucse of this, `fail` block of client never gets executed.

Please suggest.

Comment: It's very strange behaviour....

Comment: Do you have any Exception Filters or any other piece of code that catch the exception on the Web API pipeline and return OK as a result ?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: When I am making hitting the same endpoint using browser, I am getting 500 as the status code. But when the call is made through Jquery,  I am getting 200 :(

Comment: @Omar.Alani: Yes, you are correct. I have another layer between JavaScript client and the .net controller. At that layer, the status code is changed :(

Comment: @Omar.Alani: I have added another question to explaing my problem. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535525/how-to-handle-http-status-code-when-making-use-of-readasstringasync